# 401 response when posting to Firebase Cloud messaging, when server key is valid

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing sending push notifications from my google-app-engine server to client apps.
I'm receiving response 401 when sending post message to Firebase cloud messaging server (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send). I've followed instructions in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server, so I'm sending "Authorization" header with my server key. When I'm checking for validity of the key with curl:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

I'm getting response:

```
{"multicast_id":6193339963814546500,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Which should mean that my server key is valid.
I followed "Recommended Actions" for 401 described in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref
Apart from the last one: "Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server key IPs."
Can that be the cause? How to check that?

Comment: I don't think the whitelist applies here (I can't even find one in the console). The answer is almost certainly that you're using the wrong server key (probably an Android/iOS client key).

Comment: Solved the issue. It was problem with retrieving server_key from json badly

Comment: Nice! Glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. It was my mistake. I wasn't truncating json to string properly and my server key wasn't in fact a correct one. 
Sorry for bother.